# How to Automatically Link a Google Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using Google Forms to take orders with my small business and I am looking to create a Google Apps Script function that onFormSubmit will AUTOMATICALLY link the form submitter to a custom website.

Does anyone have any expertise in this? Willing to pay for such a function.

Comment: I cannot image about `Google Apps Script function that onFormSubmit will AUTOMATICALLY link the form submitter to a custom website.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: What do you wish this linking to accomplish?

Comment: The reason why I want to link to another website/webpage is to get away from the Submission Complete URL of a Google Form. If a customer reloads their browser with a completed form, a duplicate is generated and I get a notification on my phone and in my transactional database. So that is why I want to link them to a separate submission complete URL/Webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect the user from Google Forms to your page. People would abuse that way too hard (it would be really easy to phish people by showing a google sign-in clone).

Another point is that there will always be a way of resubmitting the form, and actually browsers already show a pop-up warning the user. Here is a list of things you could try to reduce the number of times this happens or their effects:

1. Disable the resubmit link if you think they are filling it twice. `Settings > Presentation > Show link to submit another response`
2. Add a custom confirmation message. The message may contain links. `Settings > Presentation > Confirmation message`
3. Make a one-time form each time (duplicate a template) which gets deleted after the `onFormSubmit` has been triggered or after a few months. If the user tries reloading it will get a not found error.
4. Check if there is an entry in the last 24/48 hours that has the exact same contents. Ignore it if you do. This could block actual requests.
5. Make a WebApp that contains the form and redirects after submit. You can use Google Apps Script.

Comment: Got it thank you for the insightful answer!